# Froala editor and React dynamic import

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, froala

I am using **Froala** editor in my create-react-app based web page. When I create a bundle, it shows that **froala_editor.pkgd.min.js** is taking substantial amount of bundle size.
To address this issue, I decided to use dynamic import, which is described here https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/code-splitting-in-create-react-app.html.
So I created a HOC

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Callback from '../Callback';

function asyncComponent(importComponent) {
    class AsyncComponent extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                component: null
            };
        }

        async componentWillMount() {
            const { default: component } = await importComponent();

            this.setState({
                component: component
            });
        }

        render() {
            const C = this.state.component;

            return C ? <C {...this.props} /> : <Callback />;
        }
    }

    return AsyncComponent;
}

export default asyncComponent;
```

And included the editor

```
const Editor = asyncComponent(() => import('../FroalaEditorComponent'));
```

I would say, that bunlde part has been resolved, as I get two chunks, one includes editor and another does not. And it has improved load times.

But I face another issue with such setup. 
When the Page with an Editor loads, it only shows few icons.

[image]

The other buttons appear, when I open console window in Chrome, not sure why is such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the editor is being initialized before all the editor plugins are loaded. All editor plugins should be loaded before initializing it in order to have the buttons in the toolbar.

Comment: Any ideas how to make sure that the plugins loads?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with React to help with this, but I believe you should import the editor component just after all the editor JS files have loaded.